# Ionic 2 / Angular - Manipulating JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm have a trouble to list a json file.

My code:

```
    this.http
      .post(link, data, options)
      .map(res => res.json().d)
      .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.profile = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(this.profile);
          },
          err => {
            console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
          }
      );
```

Console.log print this:

**Object {user: Object, class: Array(1)}**

```
{  
   "user":{  
      "name":"Name",
      "date":"19880210",
      "email":"test@test.com",
      "about":"About me",
      "picuteUrl":"http://www.url.com/Midia/User/picture.jpeg",
   },
   "class":[  
      {  
         "id":"82",
         "name":"Class 01"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can also get these values in the TypeScript file

```
console.log(this.profile.user.name);
console.log(this.profile.class[0]);
console.log(this.profile.class[0].name);
```

But in html code i dont get this values.

```
<input type="text" value="{{profile.user.name}}">
```

ERROR:

```
ion-dev.js?v=1.1.4:156 TypeError: Cannot read property 'usuario' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no where you are accessing, usuario in the provided code. You could use **`elvis/safe`** operator to check if the valaues are present

```
<input type="text" value="{{profile?.user?.name}}">
```

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan.
now it works!

Is there another way, other than the elvis operator, to load the object and then put it in the view and no longer have this problem?

Comment: it works async way, so you need to wait til you get the result. you could handle with preloader. mark as answer if it has helped